# OAuth Prompt not working in Bot Framework Emulator

Tags: oauth, bots, botframeworkemulator

I have created a bot using bot framework composer (v2.1.2) where I have used the OAuth prompt to generate token from the Azure AD. When I tested this in Emulator (4.14.1), once I clicked the OAuth button it shows the redirect URL (`https://token.botframework.com/.auth/web/redirect`) which is shown below and when I clicked the confirm sign in, a window pops up with nothing and goes off and no token is generated. I am able to get the token in the web chat as well as in teams.

[image]

[image]

[image]

1. Create a bot in Composer with OAuth prompt action to generate a token.
2. Create app registration in Azure
3. Configure OAuth connection in the bot channel

Expected behavior:

When clicked on OAuth card the bot should pop up a window for user login. But here it just open and go off without nothing.

Comment: be more specific, which kind of bot is it?